# VLC on windows 8.1 can't open files on iMac

Tags: network, imac, smb, vlc

I have an iMac running Mavericks. My music files (mp3) are stored on this machine. I also have a windows 8.1 laptop running VLC media player. I can access files on the iMac from the windows machine over my local home network using windows explorer with no problem. However VLC running on my windows 8.1 machine cannot access the files on my imac: I get an error saying "VLC cannot access the MRL."

Using VLC I can access and play music files stored on any of my windows machines, so it is not a problem with vlc getting through the firewall on my windows 8.1 machine. It seems the iMac is refusing access to VLC, though it allows access to windows explorer, ping etc.

How can I open these files?

Update: I tried different music apps running on my windows 8.1 machine besides VLC. Boom.exe and MPC-HC were not able to play the files stored on the imac (though they could both see and select them) but windows media player could see and successfully play the files.

Comment: So what are the Firewall settings for VLC on your iMac?

Comment: @Buscar: VLC is running on my windows 8.1 machine, not on my imac, so I don't have any specific firewall instructions on my iMac for VLC. Looking in System Preferences->Security->Firewall I can se that I have filesharing (AFP,SMB) set to green (allow incoming connections). I assumed that this would be sufficient to allow any external program on my local network to access files. I see that there is also a 'stealth' mode option to disable ping: this mode is not enabled.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a fix but information sharing.

My mavericks Firewall has following settings

[image: firewall]

Use the + to add and allow connection.

I set my VLC to Block for demonstration purpose.

Comment: thanks for sharing. I think my problem is to with SMB on Mavericks. I guess that windows 8.1 applications such as VLC use SMB3, which isn't supported by Mavericks 10.9.4. But that's just a guess.